# Can Rhino Mocks Write My Expect Statements For Me?

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have a set of Visual Studio Team System unit (integration really) tests that talk to a remote database.  The tests are getting too slow and unwieldy.  I'd like to replace the entire set of tests with mocked out versions.  The problem is it's painful to write all the expect statements that mimic what an entire database does.

Does anyone know of a tool or add-on that will run an existing test, figure out what the non-mocked version actually returns and write out the Expect.Call's to duplicate the functionality?  I know this is a long shot, but I feel like it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ended up writing it myself.  Here is the blog post overview:

[Write My Rhino Mocks Expect Statement](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/write-my-rhino-mocks-expect-statement.html)

And here is the CodePlex project:

[WriteMyExpectStatement](http://www.codeplex.com/WriteMyExpect)

Hope this helps someone somewhere.

Comment: The CodePlex link is dead, and the blog post is not much good without the CodePlex link. Moreover, this is essentially a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kazark, I guess Codeplex must have archived it.  I've requested they restore it.  I'm up for expanding the answer if they can or deleting it if they can't.

Comment: Codeplex said they couldn't restore the project. I tried to delete the question and answer, but couldn't, so I voted to close the question, guess that's the best I can do.