# Tool to create mock from a real execution

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mocking, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm working on this ,let's call it legacy, code that makes calls to another component using an interface (IFjuk).
I realize that mocking is generally intended for unit testing, but I thought it might be useful for a form of "system test". My primary goal is to get rid of a dependency on a piece of external hardware.
The execution makes many calls to IFjuk, which would make it cumbersome to manually write and maintain code that defines the mock expectations.

One idea I have is to use Castle Dynamic Proxy to record calls (including return values from the real component) and generate C# code from that which defines RhinoMock mocks, but I suspect someone must have built something similar already...

Is there a tool that can record calls and responses to IFjuk against the actual component, so that I can use that data to generate mocks?

Comment: This is very similar to what I want to do, but his solution seems to require a bit too much changes to the existing code for my taste. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218180/can-rhino-mocks-write-my-expect-statements-for-me

Answer (score 1):

No there is no any builtin "call tracer" available, but I think this is one of the place where AOP http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/aspect-oriented-programming-in-C-Sharp-net-part-i/ can become very useful.